# Как подставить формы в блоки?

Tags: javascript

Делаю встраиваемые формы. В сайт встраивается div с `id` формы, скрипт ищет эти div и в них должен засовывать подгруженный `html` формы. У меня не получается почему-то. Подскажите, пожалуйста:

```
function EmbedForm() { 
    var EmbedForms = document.getElementsByClassName('EmbedForm');

    for( var i = 0; i < EmbedForms.length; i++ ) { 
        key_form = EmbedForms[i].getAttribute('data-key-form');
        var url = ''+HOST+'php/formfromsite.php?act=embedform&form_key='+ key_form; 
        var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

        var xhr = new XHR();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
        FormOptions = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (FormOptions.succes == 1){
            EmbedForms[i].innerHTML = FormOptions.formhtml;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие ошибки в консоли? Что возвращает сервер?

Comment: молчит ничего не пишет

Comment: вытаскивает id элемента, но вот ничего дальше не происходит =(

Answer (score 1):

Вы открываете соединение, но не отправляете его, используйте метод

```
xhr.send(null) // у вас метод GET, поэтому в теле запроса ничего не передаем
```

Тогда у вас будет отправляться запрос, лучше после присвоения методу `onload` значения 
Можете еще использовать метод `onreadystatechange` заместо `onload`

Comment: сделал, подгружает нормально, но теперь другая проблема, если я добавляю второй элемент в который нужно загрузить форму добавляет только в какой-то один элемент, а второй получается пустым.